# How do you have custom default settings for new users in kde5 before the first login?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, user-config

> I am a kde5 system administrator with many users and how do I make it so that when a new user is created, some settings are automatically applied to them before the first login. These settings should be applied if the user is created by the kde5 system settings or the useradd command.

I have tried to copy .kde user directory but could not find it, and I can't figure out how to configure the /etc/skel directory.

[Solved]
ChatGPT
To automatically apply settings to new users in KDE5, you need to create a skeleton directory that contains the necessary configuration files. Here are the steps to do that:

Create a directory named "skel" in the /etc directory:
bash
Copy code
sudo mkdir /etc/skel
Copy the configuration files that you want to apply to new users to the /etc/skel directory. For example, to set the background image for new users, copy the background image file to /etc/skel/Pictures directory:
bash
Copy code
sudo cp ~/Pictures/background.jpg /etc/skel/Pictures/
Set the correct permissions for the files in the skel directory:
bash
Copy code
sudo chown -R root:root /etc/skel
sudo chmod -R 755 /etc/skel
Next, all new users will inherit this directory and its contents. Any new user added will automatically copy the contents of the skel directory.
The next time a new user is created using "useradd" or KDE5 system settings, the files in the /etc/skel directory will be copied to the new user's home directory automatically, and they will have the desired configuration settings from the start.